# Ruby password hashing

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble correctly hashing the passwords for new users that register on to a makeshift website. Users have a username, password and an avatar which is loaded via filename and subsequently stored onto an SQL database. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    def register(user, filename, file, password, confirm)
      if(password != confirm) then return false end
      if(not_found(user) == user) 
        user = html_clean(user)
        password = html_clean(password)
        upload_file(filename, file)
        n = SecureRandom.hex
        p = password + n
        hashed = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest p
        @db.prepare("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?,?,#{filename},
       {n}\")").execute([user,hashed])
      end
      true
    end
```

Comment: The specific problem I was having is during the @db.prepare portion, it throws out that the database column doesn't exist.

Comment: Ouch. Never *ever* use a fast hash such as SHA256 for password hashing. Always use a password hashing algorithm for password hashing, such as bcrypt (well-reviewed, well-tested, well-known, well-understood, but not fully resistant to the ever-growing computing power of GPGPUs) or scrypt (resistant to GPGPU,  but younger and thus less well-researched and tested). Also, never *ever* store password hashes unsalted.

Answer (score 4):

Use `bcrypt` for password storage, hashing validation.

Using BCrypt for password hashing has several advantages over the builtin Digest classes. Also it the built-in security. Passwords are automatically salted. Furthermore, BCrypt has a parameter cost which exponentially scales the computation time.

```
gem install bcrypt
```

An example:

#### The *User* model

```
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # users.password_hash in the database is a :string
  include BCrypt

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end
end
```

#### Creating an account

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.password = params[:password]
  @user.save!
end
```

#### Authenticating a user

```
def login
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if @user.password == params[:password]
    give_token
  else
    redirect_to home_url
  end
end
```

Links: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby

Comment: This was my idea as well, but I don't have writing permission.